# component gets props as undefined

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use navigation to navigate and pass props to another component, but for some reason, the props are getting undefined in the destination screen.

I have a main screen with flat list, each item on the flat list moves the user to a second screen with the corresponding data from the list item.

This is the main screen flat list and the navigate function:

```
async function showConversation(company: Company) { 
  const currentUser: User = await StorageHelper.retrieveEntity() as User;
  const from = currentUser.uid;
  const to = company.uid;
  
  console.log(from); <-- logs correctly
  console.log(to); <-- logs correctly
  
  navigation.navigate('Conversation', {to: to, from: from});
}

return ( 
  <FlatList<Company>
    data={companies}
    renderItem={({item}) => (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => showConversation(item)}>
        <CompanyCard company={item} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.uid}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  />
)
```

This is my Conversation screen:

```
interface conversationScreenProps {
  navigation: any;
  to: string
  from: string;
}

const ConversationScreen = ({
  navigation,
  to,
  from,
}: conversationScreenProps) => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Array<IMessage>>([]);
  const [chatMessage, setChatMessage] = useState<string>('');
  const socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:3000');
  
  console.log(to); <-- logs undefined
  console.log(from); <-- logs undefined
}
```

I saw similar questions to this one, but I still couldn't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: In react navigation 5x params are member of route prop not navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Params are passed inside the route prop they are not passed as separate prop.
You will have to access it like below

```
const ConversationScreen = ({
  navigation,
  route
}: conversationScreenProps) => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Array<IMessage>>([]);
  const [chatMessage, setChatMessage] = useState<string>('');
  const socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:3000');
  
  console.log(route.params.to); <-- logs undefined
  console.log(route.params.from); <-- logs undefined
}
```

You can check the reference here
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Answer (score 0):

You should access them like this. Because you are not passing the props directly but through react navigation.

```
let to = navigation.state.params.to
let from = navigation.state.params.from
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this now, but I'm getting a TypeError saying `navigation.state.params` is undefined. I'm trying to look for a solution for this now.